# How to iterate over an array of objects and return the key value as part of a string

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I am trying to iterate over an array of objects and return a formatted version of the key, value of each object.

```
function formattedTotalandTax() {
  let formattedData = [];
  totalAndTax = [{Total: 20.64}, {Tax: 1.64}]  
  for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(totalAndTax)) {
    formattedData.push([`${key}` + ':' + '    ' + `${value}`]);
  }
  return formattedData;
};
```

this is the result I am getting

```
0: ["0:    [object Object]"]
1: ["0:    [object Object]"]
```

I want the result to be

```
[["Total:    20.64"], ["Tax:    1.64"]]
```

Comment: there is nothing wrong with the expected output, it has been answered below!

Comment: `JSON.stringify(totalAndTax)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens, because you're trying to iterate array. You should iterate array item :)

```js
function formattedTotalandTax() {
  let formattedData = [];
  totalAndTax = [{Total: 20.64}, {Tax: 1.64}]
  for (let oneTotalAndTax of totalAndTax) {
    for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(oneTotalAndTax)) {
      formattedData.push([`${key}` + ':' + '    ' + `${value}`]);
    }
  }
  return formattedData;
};

console.log(formattedTotalandTax());
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
let totalAndTax = [{Total: 20.64}, {Tax: 1.64}]; 

let result = totalAndTax.map((obj) => {
   let arr = Object.entries(obj)[0];
   
   return [`${arr[0]}:   ${arr[1]}`];
}) 

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `map` twice like this:

```js
function formattedTotalandTax(totalAndTax) {
    return totalAndTax.map(oneTotalAndTax => 
        Object.entries(oneTotalAndTax).map(([key, value]) => `${key}:    ${value}`)
    );
}

console.log(formattedTotalandTax([{Total: 20.64}, {Tax: 1.64}]));
```